# Problem while rs.initiate() for setup docker-compose for replica set

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, replicaset

I want to setup MongoDB replica set with docker-compose with only one node. This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mongodb1:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --replSet rs0
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb1/data:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo-dev-net

  setup-rs:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongo mongodb://mongodb1:27017 --eval "rs.initiate();"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb1
    networks:
      - mongo-dev-net

networks:
  mongo-dev-net:
    driver: bridge
```

It gives me an error while trying to run command in setup-rs service. This is the error:

`Error: couldn't connect to server mongodb1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongodb1:27017 (MY_IP:27017) :: caused by :: Connection refused :`

How should I initiate replica set without using any setup.sh file with only one node? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Connection refused` means there is nothing listening on port 27017.  Is your command trying to run before the mongod has finished starting?

Comment: @Joe I just do `docker-compose up`

Comment: This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/339

Answer (score 2):

You need to first start your 2 mongodb instances and then call the initiate in a second moment (after both are started)

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose up -d

sleep 5

docker exec mongodb1 /scripts/rs-init.sh
```

And in your mongodb1 you have the `rs-init.sh` script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

mongo <<EOF
var config = {
    "_id": "dbrs",
    "version": 1,
    "members": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "host": "mongodb1:27017",
            "priority": 1
        },
    ]
};
rs.initiate(config, { force: true });
rs.status();
EOF
```

You can take a look at the detailed step by step [here](https://blog.tericcabrel.com/mongodb-replica-set-docker-compose/#automate-the-process-with-docker-compose)

PS: I didn't test the full solution

Comment: Might be worth clarifying that the second instance isn't an actual database, it's just using the same docker image to connect to the database running in the first instance to initialise it!